# Change the redirection of WordPress when database connection interrupted

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I currently have hosted a WordPress site on a free web hosting which gives a hourly quota limit for db queries. When the quota limit exceeded, WordPress automatically redirect to the WP Installation Page because it can't make a db connection. If that happen while a visitor browsing, they can reinstall the site. How can I change the redirect to another file instead of the installation page. Which file should I changed. Thanks!

Comment: Is this your answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96620/should-i-remove-install-php-and-install-helper-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found: https://wp-mix.com/wordpress-db-error-php-drop-in-template/

I think we can change that code to do what you need by combining it with `wp_redirect` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

1. Create `db-error.php` file in /wp-content/
2. Insert the below code.
3. Change the `$url` variable to the URL you want to redirect to.
   (untested)

```
<?php ob_start();
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
    header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');

    $url = 'https://another-domain.com';
    wp_redirect( $url );
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like that to test your database connection before loading wordpress :

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',$user,$pass );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    header('Location: https://yournewlocation');      
    exit();
}
```

Put this code at the top of your index.php file :

Comment: Not the best recommendations I agree, but it's my first guess